# Wait for a page to be ready before showing it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty sure that this is not possible but I could be wrong.
I've been asked to keep a web page on hold until another page is ready before showing the latter.

Consider for example pageA.html that has a link to pageB.html.
pageB has some jScript (is actually GWT but pretend you don't know) that creates the page.

The user would like to keep showing pageA until pageB is ready to show.
Is that possible, keeping the two pages separate?

Comment: have you tried using prerender? https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender and prefetch http://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch

Comment: The second page contains dynamic content and various asynchronous call so I don't know the content until I submit the first page

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at AngularJS. (SPA = Single Page Application). You can load new views ("pages") in the current page and show a loader or your current page until the loading is finished.

Comment: Do you have a sample?

Comment: http://yearofmoo-articles.github.io/angularjs-2nd-animation-article/app/#/

All the views are loaded on the background.

It's not that hard to learn AngularJS, but it's not a plugin.. It's a complete framework.

Comment: SPA would be the best option and is the way GWT should be used, but the application has been developed in multiple pages and we cannot refactor everything now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery `$(window).load(function(){});` and create an overlay on the existing page.

I.e. User loads page A and you have an overlay immediately visible blocking the visibility of the page. When the load event is triggered you can remove the overlay.

This is slightly different from what you've asked but may be an approach.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DeanWhitehouse/m9ctA/)

Comment: We already have something similar in place (a loading indicator that hide the incomplete page) but the client doesn't like it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep checking the url until the page exists. This implies the page you want to redirect to doesn't yet exist and is going to be created at some point.

The link could be

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="delayRedirectTo('my-generated-page.html');">link text</a>
```

Then wrapping some logic in the `delayRedirectTo` function.

```
function delayRedirectTo(path){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        // Status will only be 200 when the page exists
        if (xhr.readyState==4 || xhr.status == 200)
        {
            // Redirect to page.
            window.location.href = path;
        }
    }
    window.setInterval(function(){
        xhr.open("GET",path,true);
        xhr.send(); 
    }, 5000); // check every 5 seconds.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Javascript and AJax

JS on pageA.html

```
<script>
  function loadPageB(){
  var html = document.getElementById("html");
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
     html.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","pageB.html",true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
} 
</script>
```

HTML page is

```
<!-- some code here -->
<input type="button" value="go to PageB" onclick="loadPageB()"/>
<!-- some code here -->
```

In the above example after clicking on button it will load the pageB.html

Comment: But that would load the content of pageB in pageA and not actually navigate to pageB, right?